# Am I using too many functions in my DataAccess Class?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am wondering if in particular the function called `AssignDBStatusMessage` and `TryDataBaseAction` are unnecessary.  It seems to me that the logic is more cluttered if i do away with those functions.  Please provide me with your ideas and thoughts.

If you have other thoughts please let me know.

**man** is an entity class generated by entity framework. **TestDataBaseEntities** is the DBcontext item.

```
public class DataAccess
{
    // ============================
    // CRUD FUNCTIONS for MAN TABLE
    // ============================
    public bool CreateMan(TestDatabaseEntities dbEntities, out string StatusMessage, Man M)
    {
        string ErrorMessage;
        bool bSuccessful;

        bSuccessful = TryDataBaseAction(dbEntities, out ErrorMessage,
            () =>
            {
                dbEntities.Men.Add(new Man { ManID = M.ManID, Name = M.Name });
            });
        StatusMessage = AssignDBStatusMessage("Records created successfully", ErrorMessage, bSuccessful);

        return bSuccessful;
    }

    public bool UpdateMan(TestDatabaseEntities dbEntities, IQueryable<Man> query, out string StatusMessage, Man man)
    {
        string ErrorMessage;
        bool bSuccessful;

        bSuccessful = TryDataBaseAction(dbEntities, out ErrorMessage,
            () =>
            {
                foreach (Man M in query)
                {
                    M.Name = man.Name;
                }
            });
        StatusMessage = AssignDBStatusMessage("Records updated successfully", ErrorMessage, bSuccessful);

        return bSuccessful;

    }

    public bool DeleteMan(TestDatabaseEntities dbEntities, IQueryable myQuery, out string StatusMessage)
    {
        string ErrorMessage;
        bool bSuccessful;

        bSuccessful = TryDataBaseAction(dbEntities, out ErrorMessage,
            () =>
            {
                foreach (Man M in myQuery)
                {
                    dbEntities.Men.Remove(M);
                }
            });

        StatusMessage = AssignDBStatusMessage("Records deleted successfully", ErrorMessage, bSuccessful);

        return bSuccessful;
    }

    public bool ReadMan(TestDatabaseEntities dbEntities, IQueryable myQuery, out string StatusMessage, out string[,] Records)
    {
        string ErrorMessage;
        bool bSuccessful;
        string[,] TheseRecords = null;

        // hands an Action() to TryDataBase, as indicated by lambda expression in 3rd arguement.
        bSuccessful = TryDataBaseAction(dbEntities, out ErrorMessage,
        () =>
        {
            List<Man> men = myQuery.OfType<Man>().ToList();
            TheseRecords = new string[men.Count, 2];

            for (int i = 0; i < men.Count; i++)
            {
                TheseRecords[i, 0] = men[i].ManID.ToString();
                TheseRecords[i, 1] = men[i].Name;
            }
        });

        Records = TheseRecords;

        StatusMessage = AssignDBStatusMessage("Records read successfully", ErrorMessage, bSuccessful);


        return bSuccessful;
    }

    // ============================
    // SAVECHANGES FUNCTION
    // ============================
    public bool SaveChanges(TestDatabaseEntities dbEntities, out string StatusMessage)
    {
        bool bSuccessful;
        string ErrorMessage;
        bSuccessful = TryDataBaseAction(dbEntities, out ErrorMessage, () => dbEntities.SaveChanges());

        StatusMessage = AssignDBStatusMessage("Save changes Sucessful", ErrorMessage, bSuccessful);

        return bSuccessful;
    }
    // ============================
    // Helper functions?
    // ============================
    public bool TryDataBaseAction(TestDatabaseEntities MyDBEntities, out string ErrorMessage, Action MyDBAction)
    {
        UserInterface MyUI = new UserInterface();
        try
        {
            MyDBAction();
            ErrorMessage = "No Errors";
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ErrorMessage = e.ToString();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private string AssignDBStatusMessage(string SuccessMsg, string FailureMsg, bool bSuccessful)
    {
        if (bSuccessful)
            return SuccessMsg;
        else
            return FailureMsg;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not huge thoughts but a couple of things.

1. I would probably consider making the entities object a class level parameter since it seems to be used in every method.
2. I wouldn't put the success message in this class as that seems more caller dependant.  Hence I would let the caller determine what success message they want on a true result.  I would only supply a failed message to at least inform the user what happened.
3. Is this sort of a repository pattern... not sure.  But I might toy with the idea of changing DataAccess to ManRepository and getting rid of man in the function names so it's just Create, Update and Read.

i.e.

```
public class ManRespository
{
   private readonly TestDatabaseEntities _dbEntities;
   public ManRepository(TestDatabaseEntities dbEntities)
   {
      _dbEntities = dbEntities;
   }

   // Your Create, Update, Read methods here
   public DbResult Create(Man man) 
   {
      // etc
   }
}
```

1. In light of 2, I might consider not returning bool at all but rather a result class.

Something like this perhaps:

```
public class DbResult
{
   public bool Success { get; private set; }
   public String Message { get; private set; }

   private DbResult(boolean success, string message)
   {
      Success = success;
      Message = message;
   }

   public static DbResult Failed(string message) {
      return new DbResult(false, message);
   }

   public static DbResult Success(string message) {
      return new DbResult(true, message);
   }
}
```

Then an example of the one of your methods might now be simplified to:

```
public DbResult Create(Man M)
{
    return TryDataBaseAction(
        () =>
        {
            _dbEntities.Men.Add(new Man { ManID = M.ManID, Name = M.Name });
        });
}

public DbResult TryDataBaseAction(Action MyDBAction)
{
    string errorMessage = string.Empty;

    try
    {
            // What was MyUI supposed to do here?  I would think mixing UI
            // dependencies at this level was not a good idea unless it was through
            // an abstraction such as an Interface or Abstract class of some sort?
        UserInterface MyUI = new UserInterface();

        MyDBAction();       

        return DbResult.Success(string.Empty);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        errorMessage = e.ToString();
    }

    return DbResult.Failed(errorMessage);
}
```

Note:  *AssignDBStatusMessage* actually became redundant in this approach and *TryDataBaseAction* is seeming a bit weak now??

Comment: MyUI was something I forgot to remove.  In the original code, i had MyUI call its method to display output to user cause it seemed like going through less hoops and hurdles than passing it back to the main program.

Comment: On what occurances are you expecting the method to fail then?  I think it would be best to do away with the TryDataBaseAction() action altogether and put that stuff into the individual Creates, Updates as I assume they fail for different reasons??

Comment: Well, sometimes it's simply that the SQL server isn't up and running, in which case the CRUD methods would fail then.  But yes, they'd fail for different reasons otherwise, Update and Delete could fail if the targeted Record ID wasn't found, Read? i don't know why it would.  Create? possibly if the new record's ID already existed. (I still need to make a fix for that).  I am trying to plan so that I can can possibly use the CRUD functions on an alternate entity Locations, which is also a table in my entity model.  I was just trying to get a good foundation going for the man entity first.

Comment: @ArmorCode I quite like the repository pattern.  Perhaps this might be an option to explore for yourself?

Comment: I'll use it, It simplifies the code.  But I'm still not clear on what constitutes a repository pattern.  I am reading about it on this [MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx), but I feel more confused after reading it and looking at the charts.  Does this conflict with the MVC pattern I'm trying to implement? I say MVC because I want to show potential employers so that they see my code and say "Ah, ok he understands what MVC is."

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how the success message is more caller-dependent.  I mean I understand that it depends on the method which called it to determine the success message, but the calling methods (CRUD methods, are defined in the DataAccess class.  So being more caller-dependent and being that the callers are in the same class, and suggesting to define the messages outside the class is confusing to me.

Comment: My thoughts were that why do you need to supply a success message from this layer at all.  If it succeeded that's great.  If the caller wants to display a message then let them put one together.... Just my thoughts anyway.